# Extract specific info from json-list

Tags: json, lua, timeout, extract

In my system from json-call http://192.168.1.6:8080/json.htm?type=devices&rid=89 I get the output below.

```
{
   "ActTime" : 1501360852,
   "ServerTime" : "2017-07-29 22:40:52",
   "Sunrise" : "05:50",
   "Sunset" : "21:28",
   "result" : [
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjMulti2" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "AddjValue2" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "CustomImage" : 0,
         "Data" : "73 Lux",
         "Description" : "",
         "Favorite" : 1,
         "HardwareID" : 4,
         "HardwareName" : "Dummies",
         "HardwareType" : "Dummy (Does nothing, use for virtual switches only)",
         "HardwareTypeVal" : 15,
         "HaveTimeout" : true,
         "ID" : "82089",
         "LastUpdate" : "2017-07-29 21:16:22",
         "Name" : "ESP8266C_Licht1",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "PlanID" : "0",
         "PlanIDs" : [ 0 ],
         "Protected" : false,
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "-",
         "SubType" : "Lux",
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Lux",
         "TypeImg" : "lux",
         "Unit" : 1,
         "Used" : 1,
         "XOffset" : "0",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "idx" : "89"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK",
   "title" : "Devices"
}
```

'Automating' such call by the below scripttime lua-script is aimed at extraction of specific information, to be further used in applications.

The first 11 lines run without problems, but further extraction of the information is a problem.

I have tried various scriptlines to get a solution for A), B), C), D) and E), but either they generate error-report, or they don't give results: see further below for the 'best' trial-scriptlines and related results.

*To avoid misunderstanding*: those dashed commentlines in the script just below this question with A), B), C), D) and E) are only describing the desired actions/functions and are in **no** way meant as scriptlines!

**Question:**

*Help requested in the form of better applicable scriptlines for A) till E) in the trialscript at the end of this message, or hints where to find applicable example scriptlines.*

```
-- Lua-script to determine staleness, time-out and value for data from Json-call
print('Start of Timeout-script')
commandArray = {}
TimeOutLimit = 10  -- Allowed timeout in seconds
json = (loadfile "/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/lua/JSON.lua")()  -- For Linux
--  json = (loadfile "D:\\Domoticz\\scripts\\lua\\json.lua")()  -- For Windows
-- Line 07
   local content=assert(io.popen('curl "http://192.168.1.6:8080/json.htm?type=devices&rid=89"')) -- notice double quotes
   local list = content:read('*all')
   content:close()
   local jsonList = json:decode(list)
-- Line 12 Next scriptlines describe desired actions 
-- A) Extract ServerTime as numeric value (not as string)
-- B) Extract LastUpdate as numeric value (not as string)
--  Staleness = ServerTime - LastUpdate
-- C) Extract HaveTimeout as boolean (not as string)
--  If HaveTimeout and (Staleness > TimeOutlimit) then
--       Print('TimeOutLimit exceeded by ' .. (Staleness - TimeOutLimit) .. 'seconds')
--  End
-- D) Extract textstring from Type or Data
-- E) Extract numeric value from Data
print('End of Timeout-script')
return commandArray
```

For lines 11 etc, the following trial-scriptlines gave 'best' results (= no errors):

```
-- Line 11
--       local Servertime = json:decode(ServerTime)
--       print('Servertime   :  '..Servertime)
-- Line 14
--       CheckTimeOut =jsonValue.result[1].HaveTimeout -- value from "HaveTimeout", inside "result" bloc number 1 (even if it's the only one)
       CurrentServerTime =jsonValue.Servertime -- value from "ServerTime"
       CurrentLastUpdate = jsonValue.result[1].LastUpdate
       CurrentData = jsonValue.result[1].Data
-- Line 19
       print('TimeOut      : '..CheckTimeOut)
       print('Servertime   : '..CurrentServerTime)
       print('LastUpdate   : '..CurrentLastUpdate)
       print('Data-content : '..CurrentData)
print('End of Timeout-script')
return commandArray
```

**Results:**

*Without* dashes before the lines 12 and 13, respectively 15, then the following error reports:

```
660: nil passed to JSON:decode()

lua:15: attempt to index global 'jsonValue' (a nil value)
```

*With* dashes before lines 12, 13 and 15 for the trial-scriptlines shown above, according to the log no errors exist (as demonstrated by the 2 prints)

```
2017-07-31 16:30:02.520 LUA: Start of Timeout-script
2017-07-31 16:30:02.563 LUA: End of Timeout-script
```

But why no print-results in the log from Lines 20 till 23?
Not having those print-results makes it difficult to determine next steps in data-extraction, to achieve the objectives described under A) till E).

;-) Error reports generally are more useful information than "no errors, but no results"

Comment: we do not provide "directly applicable script lines". maybe you should invest a few hours into learning the very basics of Lua instead of just trying to run "borrowed examples". also if you don't share the error messages you get you cannot expect any help.

Comment: Lua is not my problem, as shown by many scripts from my hand in the Domoticz Forum. Questions rise because after study & adaptation of example scripts with json, I do not see the expected results, and cannot find explanation nor remedy. In reponse to your comment I have extended the description and rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without downloading content over the network, the working script looks like this:

```
local json = require("json")
    local jj = [[
{
   "ActTime" : 1501360852,
   "ServerTime" : "2017-07-29 22:40:52",
   "Sunrise" : "05:50",
   "Sunset" : "21:28",
   "result" : [
      {
         "AddjMulti" : 1.0,
         "AddjMulti2" : 1.0,
         "AddjValue" : 0.0,
         "AddjValue2" : 0.0,
         "BatteryLevel" : 255,
         "CustomImage" : 0,
         "Data" : "73 Lux",
         "Description" : "",
         "Favorite" : 1,
         "HardwareID" : 4,
         "HardwareName" : "Dummies",
         "HardwareType" : "Dummy (Does nothing, use for virtual switches only)",
         "HardwareTypeVal" : 15,
         "HaveTimeout" : true,
         "ID" : "82089",
         "LastUpdate" : "2017-07-29 21:16:22",
         "Name" : "ESP8266C_Licht1",
         "Notifications" : "false",
         "PlanID" : "0",
         "PlanIDs" : [ 0 ],
         "Protected" : false,
         "ShowNotifications" : true,
         "SignalLevel" : "-",
         "SubType" : "Lux",
         "Timers" : "false",
         "Type" : "Lux",
         "TypeImg" : "lux",
         "Unit" : 1,
         "Used" : 1,
         "XOffset" : "0",
         "YOffset" : "0",
         "idx" : "89"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK",
   "title" : "Devices"
}
]]
    print('Start of Timeout-script')

    local jsonValue = json.decode(jj)
    CheckTimeOut =jsonValue.result[1].HaveTimeout 
    CurrentServerTime =jsonValue.Servertime
    CurrentLastUpdate = jsonValue.result[1].LastUpdate
    CurrentData = jsonValue.result[1].Data
    print('TimeOut      : '.. (CheckTimeOut and "true" or "false") )
    print('Servertime   : '.. (CurrentServerTime or "nil") )
    print('LastUpdate   : '.. (CurrentLastUpdate or "nil") )
    print('Data-content : '.. (CurrentData or "nil") )
    print('End of Timeout-script')
```

result:

```
Start of Timeout-script
TimeOut      : true
Servertime   : nil
LastUpdate   : 2017-07-29 21:16:22
Data-content : 73 Lux
End of Timeout-script
```

Comment: @Mike_V

Apparently I was near the solution, but still some distance away.

If I substitute the line in your script

        local jsonValue = json.decode(jj)

by

         local jsonValue = json.decode(list)
that (in my opinion) should be sufficient to 'glue' the starting lines of my script and the ending lines in your script.
But I get the error report 

        660: JSON:decode must be called in method format

Cryptic for me and Google, W3, etc. do not help with explanation: what is missing or at fault?

Furthermore: why is Servertime nil as result of your example-script?